# Is there a way to get URL schemes of an app in iOS?

Tags: ios

I know there's a way to launch another app from my app through URL schemes in iOS.

The question is, I'm not sure that the app which my app to be linked to has URL schemes or not? and if there are, is there a way to get them?

Comment: The available doc for each app is a way, else you may read the Info.plist from the .ipa of an app.

Comment: Do you have a fixed list of schemes you're curious about?

Answer (score 2):

Follow the below steps to get URL schemas

- Download the .ipa from iTunes using computer
- Copy the application to desktop
- Rename it to *.zip
- Extract the *.zip
- Open the **Payload** folder
- Right click on the application and select 'Show Package    Contents' 
  then double-click the 'Info.plist' file
- Then check 'URL types' > 'Item 0' > 'URL Schemes'

Hope this will help you.